# Jquery to a asp.net control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use jquery on an Asp.net control. In asp.net id get generated from server.
so I am trying to write a selector to use jquery.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ctl00$cphBody$fv$txtDescription").val('blah');
        });
```

I need if the id **contains** 'txtDescription', I need to change the value of that textbox.
Please suggest a selector for that

Answer (score 1):

A much better choice would be to assign a css class and then use that to identify the elements.
Something like:

```
$(function(){
  $(".someClass").val('blah'); 
});
```

If that is not feasible for your current scenario, try the code below. It checks for the id's ending with txtDescription as this is what you would need):

```
$(function(){
  $("[id$='txtDescription']").val('blah'); 
});
```

If you really need contains (i.e. anywhere in the id) then try:

```
$(function(){
  $("[id*='txtDescription']").val('blah'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**please dont use**

```
  $("#ctl00$cphBody$fv$txtDescription").val('blah');
```

**use**

```
$("#<%= txtDescription.ClientID%>")  instead
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on ASP.NET 4.0, consider using the [new ClientID modes](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) to avoid having to mess with the nasty long ClientIDs in Javascript code. This will be more maintainable than using "contains" operations.